# jquery check element is not empty change class

Tags: javascript, jquery

When p.err is not empty I want to add the class p.err-wrapper.

```
<p class="err err-wrapper">not empty</p>
<p class="err"></p>


p.err {color:#ff0000, font-weight: bold; }
p.err-wrapper {background:#ffffdd; border:1px solid #ff0000; }
```

The app I am using adds an error msg over a form like this `<p class="err"><?php get(error_msg) ?></p>`

It is added to the page whether there is an error or not. As soon as there is an error `<p class="err">Your first name is missing</p>`, p.err decorates the contents of the `<p>` tag.

I want to wrap the error in a border and a background. The problems is because `<p class="err"></p>`
is not conditionally added, I get a bordered background when there it no error.

I want to add jquery that checks if `<p class="err"></p>` is not empty and then add the class p.err-wrapper, i.e. `<p class="err err-wrapper"></p>`.

I got it kind of working but i am so new at jquery.

Comment: I'm really lost trying to follow along with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
$("p.err")
.filter(function(){return $(this).text().replace(/\s/g,"").length!=0})
.addClass("err-wrapper")​​​​​​​​;​​​​​​
```

The function passed as filter will trim any empty white spaces in the content.

You can se a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/FNgDF/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:not` and `:empty` selectors.

```
$('p.err:not(:empty)').addClass('err-wrapper');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QYaJC/

Comment: I tried that but what is happening, is when <p class="err"></p> is empty .err-wrapper produces a 2px high red border. 

Basically .err-wrapper is being added regardless if the <p> tag is empty. It's 2px high because the border is 1px top and bottom and there is no text in the <p> tag.

Comment: I stand corrected, actually, it works just fine on your demo. I did not see the demo at first and tried it on jsfiddle myself but got the problem I mentioned above. THANKS!